# Can I create a npm package both deployed and published with different dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, create-react-app, npm-publish

I have created a React application (using create-react-app).
This React application contains some code that I want to publish on NPM. I managed to do it (using Rollup).
The problem is with dependencies: I need it for the react application, but I don't need any dependencies for the published package. Is there any way to have dependencies installed for the react application but not listed for publication?

I have very good reasons not to create 2 different packages by the way, I'm not looking for answer to tell me to make 2 packages.

Comment: Maybe a mono-repo architecture would be a compromise between splitting them as 2 packages, but still leaving them in the same repository for easy development?

Comment: Yes, I know about Lerna for example but if I could avoid that it's better. The thing is, over the time I will have dozens of project following this model : the simpler the setup is, the better.